# AngularFire has no exported member "InjectionToken"

Tags: angularjs, angularfire, angularfire2

I am having issues creating an angular-fire application. I was following this tutorial: https://progblog.io/Angular-2-Firebase-Tutorial-Part-1-Create-a-Firebase-3-CRUD-app-with-Angular-CLI/
But as soon as I add angular-fire to the application I am no longer able to start the "server" with ng serve,  as I get the following exception:

```
ERROR in <PATH_TO_MY_PROJECT>/node_modules/angularfire2/angularfire2.d.ts (3,10): Module '"<PATH_TO_MY_PROJECT>/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'InjectionToken'
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Can anybody tell me what might be the reason for this ? 
I have also tried to use the @Next version of angular-fire (`npm i angularfire2@next --save` ) like pointed out here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/843 but I had no success with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this tutorial is old!

Now angularfire2 is on version 4.0.0-rc0 https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

You have to follow this tutorial

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/1-install-and-setup.md

Answer (score -1):

```
 npm install angularfire2
```

Install types for firebase

```
npm install typings

typings install dt~firebase --global --save
```